# flow is unable to decide which case to select on union type

Tags: javascript, flowtype

When i try union tuple have array some length I get the error

Look at this work example where each type have different length. [Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGeOAPACoB8YAvGBWAD5gDaFAus2xQDRgB5AEYArPAGMMHANzps+IgEY6bYqTIByAIIaq-NeQ2Fd+koYAiujplwFCAJhWsDmgIomiZzQHUrNhYQAzE4uGgBafv52KoTKLA7cQegweBhgAIaKAFxETtoa-EYFYBqW1qgpaen2OYROrBruHIW+1pUZgbX1jcUA3gC+zSWtFakZACxd9KwN7vwDQw2tbWPpAKxTbLN9g-xLOxzl7ekAbJsNEStVAOznFxqHQA). *(UPD: change flow version to 0.71)*

But when I try add type with some length flow can not resolve it. [Example](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVAXAngBwKZgDKGeOAPACoB8YAvGBWAD5gDaFAus2xQDRgB5AEYArPAGMMHANzps+IgEY6bYqTIByAIIaq-NeQ2Fd+koYAiujplwFCAJhWsDmgIomiZzQHUrNhYQAzE4uGgBafqjAwAgAljAwYABOeADOAK4wGGCxAHZgAIb5eElJcElgQhIF6akERAAsYDB4uQDmGAAWYKkFALYEBalgUOU9wf52TfTOXhoAGpHydiqEyiwO3EFbDegt2QWKAFxETtoa-EYXYBqW1qj7hfYnhE6sGu4cl77WjwWBLzeH2uAG8AL5fG4-B54A4NQEzd7ufjgyHvH6-WGFACsCLYSNBEP46MJHHufwAbHj3hFMQcAOzUmkaMlAA).

```
type Step<T> = T | [T] | [T, Object];

type S3 = [Step<'Z'>]
type S4 = [Step<'X'>]

type S = S3 | S4

let a6: S = ['Z']
let a7: S = [['Z']]
```

Error:

```
11: let a7: S = [['Z']]
            ^ Could not decide which case to select. Since case 1 [1] may work but if it 
doesn't case 2 [2] looks promising too. To fix add a type annotation to array literal [3].

References:
8: type S = S3 | S4
            ^ [1]
8: type S = S3 | S4
                 ^ [2]
11: let a7: S = [['Z']]
                ^ [3]
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe you could add more detail to your question? Have you tried adding the type annotation like flow suggested? Maybe give some more context for what you're doing?